# Show url clipboard

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am coding a Spigot/Bukkit plugin in 1.8.

I a working on a GUI with items and options and I would like to make it when you click an item in the GUI it opens the link menu that says "Are you sure you want to open the following website?" and has the options "Yes" "Copy to clipboard" "No".

I tried searching online but couldn't find anything and couldn't find any methods in Bukkit or Spigot.

Is it possible to accomplish this with packets?

Comment: Just curious: Why do you think packets are the answer?

Comment: @Draco18s Since I couldn't find a method in Bukkit it has to be possible some other way.

Comment: Do you know what packets *are* and what they *do*?

Answer (score 2):

No, it cannot be done. It is a client-side action.